# Is it possible to upgrade a LTO3 drive to LTO5 or LTO6?

Tags: dell, tapedrive, lto, lto-3

We have a ML6000 Dell tape library with a LTO-3 drive (part number KU838).

Can this drive support LTO-5 or LTO-6 via firmware upgrade? I could not find any information about this on Dell pages.

Is it even physically possible to a LTO-3 driver read or write LTO-4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a hardware limitation, not software, so I don't think it can be upgraded. I've never seen any, they've always had to be replaced.

LTO drives are backwards compatible two generations for reading, meaning that an LTO-5 can read LTO-3 and LTO-4 (but not LTO-2 or below).

However they are only backwards compatible one generation for writing.

Comment: This is correct.  It's a hardware constraint - the read/write heads on an LTO drive aren't sensitive enough to read at the density utilized by higher LTO versions, and that's not something that can be remedied by updating the firmware or software.

Comment: Correct re. the upward compability, but LTO5 can write 4/5 and read 3/4/5 etc.

Comment: -1 Sorry, some of the information is incorrect, other parts are just misleading... And you take forever to get to the point.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible.

Citing [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open#Generations):

> - An Ultrium drive reads data from a cartridge in its own generation and
>     at least the two prior generations.
> - An Ultrium drive writes data to a
>     cartridge in its own generation and to a cartridge from the immediate
>     prior generation in the prior generation format.